# Detect Internet connect And switch off system automatically

Tags: internet-connection

iam using 256 kbps internet connection..so i will download in night time fully ,in that my problem is..

Some time internet connection will be disconnected, by the time sysytem will be runnig full night wastly,

so i need to avoid this problem by detecting the net connectivity..

Is there any free software, that will detect the status of internet and shutdown the system when the internet disconnected,
Or hit any exe file when internet disconnected ,so i will route it to shutdown exe shortcut .

thanks in advance

Comment: You have not mentioned what operating system you are using.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is running a script that will shut down the computer once the Internet is unreachable. Below is an example script that I whipped up (without much testing),

It uses sleep.exe which is included in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&DisplayLang=en), or another possibility is to download a similar program from [here](http://www.marcindabrowski.net/?p=122).

> @Echo Off
>  :loop
>  sleep
>   600
>  ping -n 1 www.google.com >
>   NUL
>  if errorlevel 1 shutdown
>   -s
>  goto loop

Note: The parameter of sleep depends on the version of it that you choose to use.